# Calculating the sum between 0s then start the next set of calculation between other 0s

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to calculate the sum between the zeros, and then continue on to the next set and do the same.  Would anybody know if there's a function for this?  I tried researching for the answer, but I'm not sure how to really rephrase it and had no lucky with any results.

[image: Example]

Comment: I see easy solution to obtain and output values needed in rows with `0` separators.

Comment: Meanwhile I've posted few Formula are getting the SUM, I'm also trying to create a Single Formula. If any body can suggest will be appreciated. ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do it is probably using a helper column:

- in first cell of the helper column enter `1`
- in second cell enter the formula `=IF(A3=0,1,0)+B2` and fill it down
- for the calculation of totals use this formula: `=SUMIF(B:B,D2,A:A)`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

*I'm unable to produce a single formula to SUM vales between Zeros, but these formula will help you to achieve the goal.*

[image]

**B2:** `=SUM(A2:OFFSET(A5,-1,0))`

**B3:** `=SUM(A5:OFFSET(A9,-1,0))`

**B4:** `=SUM(A9:OFFSET(A11,-1,0))`

**B5:** `=SUM(A11:OFFSET(A15,-1,0))`

**Note,**

- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.